# Hexagon shape using CSS3 or Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I wanna create a hexagon be created with pure CSS3, as shown below.
[image: CSSHEXAGON]

As you see in the image, there is a  b-g image on the background.
i have tried to create the hexagon but the text within the hexagon is not displaying properly( category1, category3 etc). its not transparent. 
somehow am not able to get the actual image, my manager is asking for.
when I ran this code, am getting the hexagon with filled-in color.

```
 

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"        
            lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>hexagon-tiles</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
           <style>        li.hex-row {
     margin-top: -10vw;
}
li.hex-row:nth-child(2n) .hexagon {
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(120deg);
}
 ul#hexagonContainer {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  }
 .hexagon {
  width: 18vw;
  background: transparent;
  height: 9vw;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 7vw;
  position: relative;
  }
 li.hex-row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  //filter: drop-shadow(0.5vw 2vw 0.5vw black);
  }
  .hexagon .hex-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
  }
  .hexagon .hex-img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   transform: rotate(-60deg);
   visibility: visible;
   box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
   background-color: #6B8E23;
  }
   .hexagon .hex-img:after {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   content: '';
   z-index: 1;
   height: 100%;
  //background-image: 
     url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg);
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
  .hex-img.hide {
  visibility: hidden; 
}

.text{
      position: absolute;
    //z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<br/>
  <ul id="hexagonContainer">
    <!-- First row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">
    <div class="text">
    <p>My Overall<br/> Score</p>
    </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
     <!-- Second row. -->
     <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       </li>
         <!-- Seventh row. -->
     </ul>       </div>       </body>       </html>
```

Comment: any idea, how to make that inner side of hexagon,blank or based on background image

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/gmhp3aw5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

Instead of the current green background that you're setting to the hexagon, try a `radial-gradient`.

```
background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0%, #6B8E23 60%);
```

Edit: This is the solution to the anchor tag, I used flex so the tag will use the entire w & h of the container and center the text.

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
    <a href="mycustomersite1.abc.com">My overall score</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.text a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am working on this. one more doubt, is it possible to provide anchor tag and link the category1,category2 etc to different pages?,ie;,when i click on category1, i should navigate to http://mycustomersite1.abc.com and on click of category2, i need to navigate to http://myproductsite1.abc.com . though i tried with <a href>      somehow, the text is not converted as hyperlinks and not getting navigated.

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if it solves your problem, if not, please show me how you're setting the anchor tag.

Comment: <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">
    <div class="text">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783951/hexagon-shape-using-css3-or-bootstrap/54785517#54785517" target="_blank"> 
ABC
 </a>
      </div>  </div>  </div>

Comment: i have applied the above code for getting the anchor tag , but somehow  it didn't work.

Comment: You're missing a open "<" and a closing tag "</div>"

Comment: Here: <div class="hexagon"><div class="hex-inner"><div class="hex-img"><div class="text"><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/54783951/…" target="_blank"> ABC </a></div></div></div></div>

Comment: background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0%, #6B8E23 60%); is the KEY!! thats awesome!! @IndPendent

Comment: one more doubt, am having : my  hexs  are not aligned properly. how to arrange them properly? Hex’s are too flat looking, Hex’s are too filled in,how to arrange the Text in the center,one middle hex needs to be bigger, so that, there is a feeling, of everything is connected.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, do you have an example? If it's for the text being centered, I already gave you the solution to that in the CSS, making the anchor tag a flex element and centering the content.